# How can I validate the formate of a date string that has timezone in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

If I have a this date: `April 14, 2022 14:00 UTC`, how I can validate that it is in `MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm <timezone>`?

I tried it with `moment` but it doesn't have format for timezone.

```
moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm',true).isValid()
```

How can I validate that the string is in `MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm <timezone>` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include " UTC" as literal text in the parse format, e.g.

```js
let date = 'April 14, 2022 14:00 UTC';

console.log(
  moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm[ UTC]',true).isValid()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Per the [moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), various offset formats are supported, so if there are other offset representations you can use multiple tests to support say "UTC" and "+00:00" (or ±HH:mm in general), e.g.

```js
['April 14, 2022 14:00 UTC',
 'April 14, 2022 14:00 +00:00',
 'April 14, 2022 14:00 +05:30'
 ].forEach(date => 
    console.log(`${date} is valid? ` +
    `${moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm[ UTC]', true).isValid() ||
       moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm Z', true).isValid()}`
    )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately *isValid* doesn't support multiple formats in the one call so you can't do:

```
moment(date, 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm[ UTC]',  'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm Z', true).isValid()
```

as only the first format is recognised.

Comment: But also per the moment documentation, you almost certainly [don't want to use moment anymore](https://momentjs.com/docs). "We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done."

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans—for those using moment.js, there is no justification to replace it unless there are missing features necessary for a particular project. It's a good library with no bugs worth mentioning. The code will continue to work as long as there is ECMAScript. The API is much more user friendly than Luxon (the suggested replacement) or the proposed Temporal object (soon to be included in ECMAScript). The Temporal API is truely unwieldy, libraries to simplify it (and to present a moment.js compatible API) are bound to proliferate.

Comment: certainly, but the odds that this is an existing codebase, in the absence of proof to that effect in the post, is pretty small. The most popuplar alternative to moment.js to date is https://date-fns.org, which covers pretty much anything people used to need moment.js for (and has 14m weekly downloads, compared to luxon's "mere" 2m).